# Cartthrob: Setting product status to sold on purchase

Tags: channel-entries, cartthrob, product

We have a product list that lists single items. At the moment the client has to go in and manually set the item to "sold" using a toggle in the product listing in the EE CMS. I'm looking to automatically set that toggle to "sold" once the payment has been successfully made.

What would be the best direction to take with this?

Answer (score 0):

By default Cartthrob can only set a "Status" after a successful order so that would be the easiest approach, use a custom status of "Sold" for successful orders. You can set these in Cartthrob settings > Orders

If your toggle is a custom field you'd probably have to write a custom extension to modify that field.